# GAE or Maps API3 Store Locator with Python? (Easy Version)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-datastore

I'm tasked with creating our Google Maps website store locator and so far all I've been able to find is old php tutorials and some new appEngine apps.

The apps look great. They seem to function as designed and it looks like this is the way I need to proceed. I even found a demos [here](http://geodatastore.appspot.com/locator) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdemos%2Fpubschools) and both are perfect.

Problem is, I'm not at the level yet to understand them in order to learn from them and start implementing my own app for our stores. I do plan on using them to learn, but at the moment I'm not at that level yet so I'm not even really learning anything by examining the code.

Is there anything I can use at the moment that is a plugin option while I learn this? Perhaps any python tutorials out there hiding somewhere? I can learn these demos but I really need something for the time being while I'm figuring it all out.

Comment: For how many stores are we talking about?

Comment: There's like ten right now. It's growing but I assume I can always continue to add locations. I'm using a standard Google map right now where I just got the lat/longs of the ten right now and plotted them.

Answer (score 0):

This [demo from 2008](http://wtp2.appspot.com/AppEngineMapDemo.htm) might be a bit old but will put you on the right tracks.

There is also [locator](http://code.google.com/p/geodatastore/source/browse/trunk/locator.py) in geodatastore. [Demo](http://geodatastore.appspot.com/locator)

Comment: The first one is for users pinning photos on a map. I don't know how I can use that one. The second looks more in tune with what I need but the project page says it's obsolete so I'm guessing that's not how it's done nowadays. I'll investigate to see if they are linking to a more current example but I didn't see one on my first readthrough.